# Is there a way to make HTML Canvas unlimited in size

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

### Good Day everyone,

I am working on a project that represents data on a colored line.

For example if you give me 300 samples of the color of the sky throughout the day. I would want to plot them on a line like this:

[image: Single line of color data]

The bright colors on the left show the daytime and the dark on the right show the night time.

That's easy enough, however for my real project I have about a million samples instead of 300. I want to use this data to make a line similar to above but 1,000,000 pixels wide, by 16 high.

It has to be in an image format because I will then run this image through different image compression algorithms (ie, jpg, jpg2000, webp ect..) and search for patterns within the results.

I thought to use HTMl Canvas for this, however the max width of html canvas in every majoy browser is much less than a million.

**Chrome:**

Maximum height/width: 32,767 pixels

**Firefox:**

Maximum height/width: 32,767 pixels

**IE:**

Maximum height/width: 8,192 pixels

The total area of the image is very normal, it's just the width that Canvas doesn't like.

Is there a way to turn these limits off in the browsers? Or is there another programming environment that could easily be setup to to build a picture like this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there any reason why you need an actual image rather than just working with the raw values? Also why don't you just write some simple, uncompressed image file such as BMP or TGA, where you just write a simple header and then the raw pixel data?

Comment: @Mario Thank you for your response. Saving it as an image is best because of compression algorithms I want to test on it are all based on images. Saving it as BMP is an interesting idea I didn't think of. I will have to look into the specs of what it takes to make the header. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: most probably you are using wrong tools. If you need to get images, no need to use browser. Try adobe photoshop or something similar.

Comment: Not there is no way, and there is no other programming environment that will fulfill your request, because the file formats you want to test do themselves have width restrictions smaller than your requirement. (65,535 for JPEG, 16383 for webp). I'm not clear as what is your end goal, but you might simply want to analyze smaller samples, before merging the results.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for display purpose only and there is restriction to use JavaScript then ideal solution would be to split your data into chunks and add navigation buttons. At a particular time show only a part of your image and when a person navigate `prev/next` at that time re-render your image. See mockup below

[image]